# Проблема при INSERT большого (>4) json массива в MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, json

Уважаемые, подскажите, пытаюсь добавить INSERTом json (массив из более чем 4 групп элементов) в MySQL и в итоге ничего не добавляется.

Пример JSON-файла:

```
[{
    "f_name" : "1",
    "l_name" : "Samanta",
    "class"  : "XII",
    "section": "A",
    "roll"   : "1"
},
{
    "f_name" : "2",
    "l_name" : "Roy",
    "class"  : "XI",
    "section": "A",
    "roll"   : "3"
},
{
    "f_name" : "3",
    "l_name" : "Gupta",
    "class"  : "XI",
    "section": "B",
    "roll"   : "5"
},

{
    "f_name" : "4",
    "l_name" : "Chakraborty",
    "class"  : "XII",
    "section": "A",
    "roll"   : "9"
},
{
    "f_name" : "5",
    "l_name" : "Chakraborty",
    "class"  : "XII",
    "section": "A",
    "roll"   : "9"
},
{
    "f_name" : "6",
    "l_name" : "Chakraborty",
    "class"  : "XII",
    "section": "A",
    "roll"   : "9"
}]
```

Структура таблицы (всё VARCHAR): f_name, l_name, class, section, roll.

Сам запрос в MySQL:

```
 foreach($data_array as $row) {
 $query .= "INSERT INTO `pros` set 
                        `f_name`  = '".$row['f_name']."',
                        `l_name`  = '".$row['l_name']."', 
                        `class`   = '".$row["class"]."',
                        `section` = '".$row["section"]."', 
                        `roll`    = '".$row["roll"]."';";
 }
```

При добавлении до 4-х групп в массиве - все отлично. Больше - не вставляет вообще ничего. В чем может быть проблема? Возможно есть какие-либо ограничение на INSERT?

Спасибо!

Comment: Как вы храните это в базе, как записываете, сколько данных в группе, 1 2 штуки или 5 миллионов?

Comment: что говорит `show variables like “max_allowed_packet”;` ?

Comment: @defrag, max_allowed_packet = 1048576

Comment: Посмотрите что выводит `mysqli::$error` (`mysqli_error()`) после выполнения проблемного запроса.

Comment: Повысил значение  max_allowed_packet в несколько раз, но так ничего и не изменилось. В Хроме выводит ошибку: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: У вас в json-e после первых трех элементов есть запятые, а дальше их нет. Это опечатка, ошибка, etc?

Comment: возможно проблема в том , что в вашем массиве нет запятых после 4го элемента?

Comment: С запятыми, это просто опечатка тут (подправил). В самом массиве они присутствуют

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сначала собрать все значения, затем другой командой вставить их в базу. Пример:

```
 $data = [];
 foreach($data_array as $row) {
     $firsnName = mysql_real_escape_string($row['f_name']);
     $lastName  = mysql_real_escape_string($row['l_name']); 
     $class     = mysql_real_escape_string($row["class"]);
     $section   = mysql_real_escape_string($row["section"]); 
     $roll      = mysql_real_escape_string($row["roll"]);

     $data[] = "('$firsnName', '$lastName', '$class', '$section', '$roll')";
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO pros (f_name, l_name, class, section, roll) values ";
 $sql .= implode(',', $data);
```