# В базу mysql не могу записать строку json массивом через php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Что я делаю не так? на странице отображается нормально, а вот в базу идет только последнее значение. Данные передаются в таком виде[28,35,198] потом идет выборка названия ['28'=>'боевик']

```
$genre = file_get_contents('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key= ... &language=ru-RU');
$js_gen = json_decode($genre, true);

$a = json_encode ($row['genre_ids'],JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$obj = json_decode($a,true);

foreach ($js_gen['genres'] as $gen) {
    $id = $gen['id'];
    $name = $gen['name'];

    foreach($obj as $item) { 
        $uses = $item; 
        if ($uses == $id) {
            $ar = array($name);
            $result = implode(', ', $ar);
            $ft = $result." ";
            $sql = "UPDATE `videos` SET `series`='$ft' WHERE name='$ch'";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Во-первых, переменная `$ch` нигде не определена, а значит может случаться много неожиданного. Во-вторых, переменная `$ft` обновляется в каждом цикле, там не может быть больше одного элемента.

Comment: $ch у меня определена я просто не стал указывать она проходит отлично

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён.

Перебрал массив по значениям, собрал и передал в базу. Помогла [эта тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810992/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-insert-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-4-json-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-mysql?rq=1).

```
$V0 = $genre_ids[0];
$V1 = $genre_ids[1];       
$data=[];
foreach ($array2 as $id=>$series) {
    if ($V0 == $id) {
       $a = $series;
    } else{}
    if ($V1 == $id) {
        $b = $series;
    } else{}

}
$data[] = "$a, $b"; 
$gt = implode(', ', $data);
```